# how to send a pdf file from android to wifi printer programatically

Tags: android

I am able to connect to wifi device (printer). Now i want to print a pdf file programatically using wifi connection. can someone tell me how to do it because i am not getting any way to do it. Please help me !!

Thanks,
Bhushan

Comment: hi did you find any solution